# How to derive ensemble average from partition function in lattice system?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, computational-physics, ising-model, partition-function

I am considering a lattice model with $N$ sites. Each site is assigned with three possible spins. The number of these three possible spins are $N_1$, $N_2$ and $N_3$. So $N=N_1+N_2+N_3$. If I can numerically evaluate the partition function of this system, what should I do to find $<N_1>$ (ensemble average) from the partition function? Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about the general relationship between the partition function and the ensemble averaged quantities, or are you interested in the most efficient and stable way to compute these quantities numerically?

Comment: I am asking about the general relationship between the partition function and the ensemble average.

Comment: In order to derive information on the expectation of some quantity, $N_1$ say, from the partition function, the latter has to include a factor of the form $e^{h N_1}$. Indeed, computing the derivative of the logarithm of the partition function w.r.t. $h$ then yields the expectation of $N_1$. More generally, the $k$th derivative yields the $k$th cumulant of $N_1$. If you are interested in expectations of more general quantities, then the partition function does not suffice, you need to work with the Gibbs distribution itself.

Comment: @Yvan Velenik, I have $N_1$ in the energy, but I also have spin-spin interactions between neighbors and the these interactions are all kronecker delta functions, say it will be 1 if the pair of spin is $(1,2)$.

Comment: You should write down explicitly your partition function if you want a specific answer.